# Удаление кнопки из активити после нажатия

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout

Есть активити, на активити расположена кнопка, по нажатию на кнопку выполняется некоторое действие. Вопрос: как сразу же, без перезапуска активити удалить эту самую кнопку (на которую нажали) при положительном выполнении действия?

ПС: Прошу прощения, вчера хотел один вопрос задать по поводу чекбокса, но разобрался раньше, чем написал и закрыл страницу, сегодня задал вопрос, а название еще со вчерашнего дня осталось, а я и не заметил... В общем чекбокса нет в активити, есть только одна кнопка, по нажатию на которую происходит определенное событие, которое может вернуть либо true, либо false, так вот, как сразу же удалить кнопку, если событие вернуло true? Именно сразу же, без перезапуска активити

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:text="Funny button" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="New CheckBox" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivit.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
CheckBox chkBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    chkBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    chkBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Я понимаю, что удаление и изменение видимости это разные вещи. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это то что Вам нужно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, с названием произошли некоторые заминки, т.е. у меня активность без чекбокса, но вам +1

Answer (score 2):

Можно по разному. Например просто удалить нужную вьюху из родительского контейнера методом `removeView(View v)` как-то так:

```
View checkBox=...;
ViewGroup containerThatHoldsCheckBox = (ViewGroup) checkBox.getParent();
containerThatHoldsCheckBox.removeView(checkBox);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, с названием заминка вышла, +1 вам

Comment: @ВладиславГоловлёв, Вне зависимости от того какой тип у вас имеет подлежащия удалению вьюха, оба предложенных варианта сработают. Просто по разному. Но, т.к. вы не уточнили зачем вам всё это надо, то выбирвйте сами подходящий вариант.